# Maybe in room not returning data but if i do query with aysnctask it returns data?

Tags: android, rx-android, android-room, reactive

I am trying to get data from room using maybe/Flowable  its returns nothing but if i try with AsyncTask its returns data .

**Here my query:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Media WHERE path LIKE :path")
Maybe<Media> getMediaByPathTest(String path);
```

**and code in Activity:**

```
                AppDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).mediaDao()
                    .getMediaByPathTest(getCurrentMedia().getPath())
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(media -> {

                                if (media != null && media.isFavourite()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SingleMediaActivity.this,
                                            "Bingo I m favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            }, throwable -> {
                            }
                            , () -> {
                            });
```

its show error

W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

what i am doing wrong and how to do it right?

Comment: maybe it only allows to run queries in a worker thread. check the logcat, you probably have an exception

Comment: Have you confirmed there are actual objects in your db? Is it not getting to the onError call? Or the onSuccess call at all? Or with a null object? Could you also post the asynctask call you make in order for it to work.

Comment: Also, you do a SELECT * query, but you only return one object. Shouldn't that be a List<Media>?

Comment: @TimKranen yes there are actual objects in db .. I checked logcat .its shows error ...W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: That's odd, since you are subscribing on the io scheduler that shouldn't happen. Are you still using the subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) line?

Comment: @TimKranen yes i am using subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

Answer (score 2):

You switched around the observeOn and subscribeOn. You're subscribed on the main thread (preventing you from accessing the database). Simply switch those:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: @UsmanSaeed No problem, if you like the answer please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do Room Operation in thread so.

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: thanks for your answer : my problem is already solved doing this